# Best practice to get a dropped column in dplyr tbl_df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I remember a comment on r-help in 2001 saying that `drop = TRUE` in `[.data.frame` was the worst design decision in R history.

`dplyr` corrects that and does not drop implicitly. When trying to convert old code to `dplyr` style, this introduces some nasty bugs when `d[, 1]` or `d[1]` is assumed a vector.

My current workaround uses `unlist` as shown below to obtain a 1-column vector. Any better ideas?

```
library(dplyr)

d2 = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = (1:5) ^ 2)
str(d2[,1]) # implicit drop = TRUE
# int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5

str(d2[,1, drop = FALSE])
# data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5

# With dplyr functions
d1 = data_frame(x = 1:5, y = x ^ 2)
str(d1[,1])
# Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5

str(unlist(d1[,1]))
# This ugly construct gives the same as str(d2[,1])
str(d1[,1][[1]])
```

Comment: Why not just use `d1[[1]]`

Comment: Works too. Got lost in [[]] space. Please post as answer as a reference. I have posted this summary because I could not find it on SO and in the docs. If someone found a caveat in the `dplyr` docs, please add link here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the `[[` extract function instead of `[`.

```
d1[[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

If you use a lot of piping with dplyr, you may also want to use the convenience functions `extract` and `extract2` from the `magrittr` package:

```
d1 %>% magrittr::extract(1) %>% str
## Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
##   $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
d1 %>% magrittr::extract2(1) %>% str
##  int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or if `extract` is too verbose for you, you can just use `[` directly in the pipe:

```
d1 %>% `[`(1) %>% str
## Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
##   $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
d1 %>% `[[`(1) %>% str
##  int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: `magrittr::extract(1)` has been mentioned in another SO thread. It's a bit verbose and not very convenient when you need several columns.

Comment: `[[`(1): nice demonstration, but one of the reasons why many people think R is second to Perl as a write-only language.

Comment: Where do `\`[\`(1)` and `\`[[\`(1)` come from, i.e. where can I find some documentation on this? And why would I have to put a named vector in quotes when I want to use extract2, i.e. `extract2("x")

Comment: @dapperdan: They are the regular extraction functions for data.frames. You can get help like usual with ?\`[\` or ?\`[[\` or better with ?\`[.data.frame\` to get the data.frame-specific help.

Comment: Thanks, that reply was faster than me fumbling with the formatting of my comment. I am somewhat familiar with the extraction functions, as in df["x"] and df[["x"]], (or rather am just learning this in the context of Hadley's world). What I cannot find in the docs is the use of `[[`(1) vs [[1]]. I.e. why one cannot use the latter in a pipe as opposed to the former, for example