# Difference between data[ , "col"] and data$col

Tags: r, dataframe

From other answers on this site on similar questions, and e.g. from pages like http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-frame-column-vector , it seems that I extract a variable from a `data.frame`, `data[ , "col"]` and `data$col` should yield the same result. But now I have some data in Excel:

```
LU  Urban_LU    LU_Index    Urban_LU_index
Residential Residential 2   0
Rural residential   Residential 3   0
Commercial  Commercial  4   1
Public institutions including education Industrial  5   1
Industry    Industrial  7   2
```

)

and I read it with `read_excel` from the `readxl` package:

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("data.xlsx", "Sheet 1")
```

Now I extract a single variable from the data frame, using `[` or `$`:

```
data[ , "LU"]
# Source: local data frame [5 x 1]
# 
#                                        LU
#                                     (chr)
# 1                             Residential
# 2                       Rural residential
# 3                              Commercial
# 4 Public institutions including education
# 5                                Industry

data$LU
# [1] "Residential"                             "Rural residential"                      
# [3] "Commercial"                              "Public institutions including education"
# [5] "Industry"                               

length(data[ , "LU"])
# [1] 1
length(data$LU)
# [1] 5
```

Also, what I find suspicious are the classes of the data obtained from `read_excel` and the data which results from the two different modes of extraction:

```
class(data)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

class(data[ , "LU"])
# [1] "tbl_df"     "data.frame"

class(data$LU)
# [1] "character"
>
```

So what's the difference between `[ , "col"]` and `$col`? Am I missing something from the manuals or is this a special case? Also, what's with the `tbl_df` and `tbl` class identifiers? I suspect that they are the cause of my confusion, what do they mean?

Comment: Yes, this is a special case.  You have entered Hadley's world.  If you do `data <- as.data.frame(data)` you should be good when doing `data[, "LU"]`.  It's due to using `readxl` that you need to do this.

Comment: `data` is not a "real" data.frame.

Comment: Right - indeed that makes it work. For brevity I left out of my original question that I already found it suspicious that the readxl documentation didn't explicitly document the return type. So is there somewhere where I can read up on what's going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of an extended comment:

The fact that `readxl::read_xl` returns output of class `tbl_df` seems poorly documented in `?read_xl`. This behaviour was mentioned in the [announcement of `readxl` on the RStudio blog](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/15/readxl-0-1-0/) though:

"[`read_xl` r]eturns output with class `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")`"

To learn more about `tbl_df`, we need to consult the `dplyr` help pages. In the **Methods** section of `?dplyr::tbl_df`, we find that
"`tbl_df` implements two important base methods: `[` Never simplifies (drops), so always returns `data.frame`".

For more background, read about the `drop` argument in `?[.data.frame`.

Related Q&A: [Extract a dplyr tbl column as a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618423/extract-a-dplyr-tbl-column-as-a-vector) and [Best practice to get a dropped column in dplyr tbl_df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782354/best-practice-to-get-a-dropped-column-in-dplyr-tbl-df).

See also [the 'original' issue on github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/587) and the discussion therein.